# c++ нужно из структуры взять всех мужчин, живущих в одном доме

Tags: c++, c

Есть структура: ФИО, возраст, пол, улица, дом, квартира.
Нужно сделать подсчет, сколько в каждом доме живёт мужчин.
Как подсчитать самих мужчин понятно, но, как сделать именно выборку по дому?

```
struct anket{
   string firstname;
   string lastname;
   string midlename;
   string street_name;
   string house_number;
   int apartment_number;
   string gender;
   int yo;
};

int main(){
int n,m=0,w=0;
cout<<"Write please n: ";
cin>>n;
anket im[n];
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"Write firstname: ";
    cin>>im[i].firstname;
    cout<<"Write lastname: ";
    cin>>im[i].lastname;
    cout<<"Write midlename: ";
    cin>>im[i].midlename;
    cout<<"Write name of street ";
    cin>>im[i].street_name;
    cout<<"Write number of house: ";
    cin>>im[i].house_number;
    cout<<"Write number of apartment: ";
    cin>>im[i].apartment_number;
    cout<<"Write gender(m/w): ";
    cin>>im[i].gender;
    cout<<"Write years old(yo): ";
    cin>>im[i].yo;
}
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    if( im[i].gender == "m"){
        m++;
    }
    else{
        w++;
    }
}
cout<<"Mans: "<<m<<endl;
cout<<"Womans: "<<w<<endl;
}
```

Вот по сути, что я сделал, но так и не понял, как именно сверить еще и по дому, ведь я не знаю какой номер дома введут.

Comment: Вероятно, помимо самой структуры у Вас есть их массив. А сделать учёт дома не сложнее пола, просто в цикле проходим по массиву, сверяем и пол, и дом, и что её нужно.

Comment: Для этого нужна группа крастоток . Мужики сами пойдут...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм поиска совпадений по полу и дому таков:

```
// искомое значение – число верных совпадений
int matches = 0;

// параметры фильтрации - пол и дом
string gender = "m";
string house = "";
cin >> house;

// цикл по всем элементам
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // сверяем нужные параметры
    if (im[i].gender == gender && im[i].house_number == house)
        matches++;
}

// готово, переменная matches хранит число нужных совпадений
```

---

P.S. Советую сохранять анкеты в файл, чтобы не вводить каждый раз вручную, но быстро тестировать алгоритм. Также, можно поставить в `main` цикл, который будет постоянно спрашивать, какое действие совершить (и выходить по одному из действий), чтобы не перезапускать программу каждый раз.

Comment: а мне кажется  вам стоит проверить, не перепутали ли с альгоритмом проверки?

Comment: теперь все в норме

Comment: Огромное спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Если есть последовательность, и нужно сравнивать элементы по какому то критерию, лучше сразу написать компаратор, а дальше разбираться как решить.

Можно решить одним  стандартным альгоитмом, а можно (но лучше пользоваться готовым  быстрым и безопасным альгоритмом) и  написать цикл подсчета. В любом случаи предикат (компаратор) будет обслуживать коду.

Comment: Спасибо ,буду знать,как оптимизировать.Спасибо еще раз))

Comment: Я невнимателен был с условием задачи,  потому удалю вариант решения